# Move aggregate logic to separate function in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Please correct me if I'm using the wrong terminology or description, but I have business logic within an aggregate function (MIN and MAX). I wish to move to the logic to it's own function. I wish to do this so I don't have to make multiple changes in different locations when the client requests. I have the following

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
        DATA_MONTH,
        DATA_DATE,
                CASE 
                  WHEN MIN(DATA_YEAR) = MAX(DATA_YEAR) 
                       AND MIN(DATA_YEAR) = @BEGIN_YR THEN 'Started' 
                  WHEN MIN(DATA_YEAR) = MAX(DATA_YEAR) 
                       AND MIN(DATA_YEAR) <> @CURRENTFY THEN 
                  CAST((MIN(DATA_YEAR) %100)-1 AS VARCHAR) 
                  + '/' 
                  + CAST(MIN(DATA_YEAR)%100 AS VARCHAR) 
                  WHEN MIN(DATA_YEAR) <> MAX(DATA_YEAR) 
                       AND MIN(DATA_YEAR) = @BEGIN_YR THEN 
                  'Started' + ' from ' 
                  + CAST((MAX(DATA_YEAR) %100)-1 AS VARCHAR) 
                  + '/' 
                  + CAST(MAX(DATA_YEAR)%100 AS VARCHAR) 
                  ELSE CAST((MIN(DATA_YEAR) %100)-1 AS VARCHAR) 
                       + '/' 
                       + CAST((MIN(DATA_YEAR) %100) AS VARCHAR) 
                       + ' through ' 
                       + CAST((MAX(DATA_YEAR) %100)-1 AS VARCHAR) 
                       + '/' 
                       + CAST(MAX(DATA_YEAR)%100 AS VARCHAR) 
                END                                 AS [STATUS] 
FROM   TABLE_A 
WHERE   DATA_MONTH IN ('03', '04')
        AND DATA_DATE = '01'
GROUP  BY DATA_MONTH, 
          DATA_DATE
```

Which I would like to change it to this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
        DATA_MONTH,
        DATA_DATE,
        dbo.getStatus(DATA_YEAR) AS [STATUS]
FROM   TABLE_A 
WHERE   DATA_MONTH IN ('03', '04')
        AND DATA_DATE = '01'
GROUP  BY DATA_MONTH, 
          DATA_DATE
```

The logic for `getStatus()` has the case statements and can output:

```
NULL
Started
15/16
Started from 15/16
15/16 through 16/17
```

My question is how can I restructure my logic to make this possible as I have a `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: Are you asking how to create a user defined aggregate function? Like so: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182741(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: You are grouping by **month** and **date** and then computing max(**year**)?

Comment: I misread this, it looks like they are not using any of the data in the CASE statement in the aggregation.  You should be able to write a normal UDF that takes the 4 variables in and spits out the output for each row.  I revised my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a scalar user defined function and use it in the SELECT.  Since it needs to be aggregated, you should be able to throw a MAX around it.

Although, I'd be interested to see if this works.

Nicarus is probably right and that you need a user defined aggregate function.

```
USE [AdventureWorks2012]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TABLE_A]    Script Date: 7/20/2016 3:23:39 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TABLE_A](
    [DATA_DATE] [date] NULL,
    [DATA_MONTH] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DATA_YEAR] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

INSERT INTO TABLE_A SELECT CAST ('2016-03-02'  as DATE) AS DATA_DATE, 3 as DATA_MONTH, 2016 AS DATA_YEAR 

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getStatus(@MAXYR int, @MINYR int, @BEGIN_YR int ,@CURRENTFY int)  
RETURNS varchar(30)
AS   
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @ret varchar(30);  
    SELECT @ret = CASE 
                  WHEN @MINYR = @MAXYR 
                       AND @MINYR = @BEGIN_YR THEN 'Started' 
                  WHEN @MINYR = @MAXYR 
                       AND @MINYR <> @CURRENTFY THEN 
                  CAST((@MINYR %100)-1 AS VARCHAR) 
                  + '/' 
                  + CAST(@MINYR%100 AS VARCHAR) 
                  WHEN @MINYR <> @MAXYR 
                       AND @MINYR = @BEGIN_YR THEN 
                  'Started' + ' from ' 
                  + CAST((@MAXYR %100)-1 AS VARCHAR) 
                  + '/' 
                  + CAST(@MAXYR%100 AS VARCHAR) 
                  ELSE CAST((@MINYR %100)-1 AS VARCHAR) 
                       + '/' 
                       + CAST((@MINYR %100) AS VARCHAR) 
                       + ' through ' 
                       + CAST((@MAXYR %100)-1 AS VARCHAR) 
                       + '/' 
                       + CAST(@MAXYR%100 AS VARCHAR) 
                END 
    RETURN @ret;  
END; 

DECLARE @BEGIN_YR INT = 2;
DECLARE @CURRENTFY int = 2016;

SELECT DISTINCT 
DATA_MONTH,
DATA_DATE,
dbo.getStatus(MAX(DATA_YEAR), MIN(DATA_YEAR), @BEGIN_YR, @CURRENTFY)  as STATUS
FROM TABLE_A
GROUP BY DATA_MONTH, DATA_DATE
```

Comment: I don't think that would work. The OP's code makes use of aggregate functions, so a scalar row-by-row function would not apply here. For instance, this is used in the case logic: `MIN(DATA_YEAR) = MAX(DATA_YEAR)`. Your code would meet that condition 100% of the time since `DATA_YEAR` is a single value.

Comment: So, having the MAX(dbo.getStatus(MAX did NOT Work, as you can't have an aggregation inside an aggregation.  But without the first MAX it worked.

Comment: Your solution did work! I had to remove the MAX around it because I was getting an error `Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery`. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sweet!  This was a good question.  Aggregations can be funky.

Comment: Thanks again. I was unsure how to describe the question to search for help. Any suggestions on changing the question title so others can find your solution?